# Invoke a function if it has a defined Decorator Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I don't know if I'm using the wrong pattern or what. I'm have a standard class and 3 decorators:

```
MyClass, Dec1, Dec2, Dec3.
```

everyone implements `MyClassInterface { getDescription(), addDescription(String t)  }`.
But Dec2 has also the function `{ specialFunction() }`.

I create an instance:

```
MyClassInterface instance = new Dec1(new Dec2(new Dec3(new MyClass())));
```

then I would call the specialFunction, but I can't! If I would have done this with Dec1 that extends Dec2, that extends Dec3, that extends MyClass,  would have been possible.

It would be nice having a function like

```
decoratorInstance = instance.hasDecorator(Dec2)
decoratorInstance.specialFunction()
```

But I don't know if it is possible without making a huge pattern mistake.

Example Use Case:
You have a main GUI with 2 panels. One day I would add another panel

```
class GUI {
   GUI(){
     addPanel(pane1);
     addPanel(pane2);
   }

}

class GUIExtendedSpecial extends GUIDecorator{
   GUIExtended(GUIInterface g){
     super(g);
     addPanel(awesomePanel);
   }

   specialFunction(){}
}

class GUIExtendedWrapper extends GUIDecorator{
   GUIExtended(GUIInterface g){
     super(g);
     addPanel(addAnotherPanel);
   }

}

GUIInterface gui = new GUIExtendedWrapper(new GUIExtendedSpecial(new GUI()));

// and now I would call the specialFunction in some way (right now are just fantasy)
1) gui.specialFunction()
2) if(gui.hasDecorator(GUIExtendedSpecial)!=null) gui.hasDecorator(GUIExtendedSpecial).specialFunction()
3) if(gui instanceof GUIExtendedSpecial) gui.specialFunction()
```

Comment: Although design patterns are generic, it would be nice to have some context here so we can know that maybe you don't need decorator? Or maybe you're using it wrong? Or maybe you can use it better? So, which problem do you try to solve?

Comment: The decorator pattern has nothing to with what you want to accomplish, because `Dec2` doesn't decorate functionality of `MyClassInterface`, but introduces new functionality that has nothing in common with already existing.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I said, I don't know if I'm using the right pattern, and I'm opened to new solutions. what should I do?

Comment: I believe the pattern you're looking for is Composition.

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev I thought about it, but i didn't come out with a valid solution, could you write down an example?

Comment: Rodi. Its not exactly clear what you are trying to do however. If special function can be called form the interface it should obviously be implemented by all classes. The decorator in its traditional sense would add addition functionality to some function. See http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern. Here operation are being called by all the classes however based on the decoration structure operation would do different things.

Answer (score 0):

> // and now I would call the specialFunction in some way (right now are just fantasy)
>   1) gui.specialFunction()
>   2) if(gui.hasDecorator(GUIExtendedSpecial)!=null) gui.hasDecorator(GUIExtendedSpecial).specialFunction()
>   3) if(gui instanceof GUIExtendedSpecial) gui.specialFunction()

I think you're looking for the [template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). Specifically, you need a hook for that segment of code, so that concrete decorator classes may do what they want during that time. So add `guiHook()` to the root of your decorator class hierarchy `MyClass`, and leave empty implementations in classes that don't use the hook, but add implementations in the classes that do use it (i.e. add `specialFunction()` to `Dec2`'s `guiHook()`. Keep in mind that you may need to pass some variables into `guiHook()`).